# Google Chromecast: why smooth streaming LIVE drives the application to a "LOAD_FAILED" media error?

Tags: javascript, chromecast, smooth-streaming

I need some help in understanding what in my Chromecast Javascript application is going wrong.
My goal is to cast a LIVE through an isml format and manage its reproduction via Chromecast developer library. 
When I try to play the live content I receive back an error on the receiver application.

Can you give me an example of a working code to correctly load a smooth streaming live?

Note that the server sends correctly the CORS headers.

This is the stack trace on the receiver app console:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable. media_player.js:103
 [  1.047s] [cast.player.api.Player] sourceclose
 media_player.js:23
 [  1.049s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Opening Xhr [GET .../Events(2014_2_7_9_52_35)/QualityLevels(400000)/Fragments(video=49999920) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [  1.050s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Will abort after 10000ms if incomplete, xhr2 false [GET http://.../Events(2014_2_7_9_52_35)/QualityLevels(400000)/Fragments(video=49999920) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [  1.051s] [goog.net.XhrIo] Sending request [GET http://.../Events(2014_2_7_9_52_35)/QualityLevels(400000)/Fragments(video=49999920) -1]
 media_player.js:23
 [  1.242s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Load metadata error
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  1.248s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Resetting media element
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  1.254s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Sending error message to 5:client-...
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  1.256s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] IPC message sent: {"namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"5:client-...","data":"{\"requestId\":...,\"type\":\"LOAD_FAILED\"}"}
 cast_receiver.js:19
 [  1.108s] [cast.player.api.Player] error
 media_player.js:23
Fatal Error - 1 index.html?Debug=true:70
 [  1.112s] [cast.player.api.Player] unload 0
```

Thanks!
C.

Comment: We would need more information to be able to help you, please contact our support.

Comment: we contacted your support but we have not yet received a reply